# How to excute commands over SSH in a batch file?

Tags: linux, ssh, batch-file

I'm looking to, all in the course of one batch file:

1. ssh into a remote computer
2. execute commands (per the batch file) on the remote host.

What options do I need to add to the ssh invocation so that the batch file executes the lines following the ssh invocation over the connection?

e.g., with sftp it's simply adding a -b /dev/stdin and then << EOF at the end; how do I do this with SSH?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just run

```
ssh machine_name < batch_file.sh
```

to run all commands in `batch_file.sh` on `machine_name`. Works with at least OpenSSH. If you want to enter those commands by yourself before opening `ssh`, you can use

```
ssh machine_name << EOF
```

Comment: Awesome---is there a way to throw literal commands through the pipe?

Comment: Of course. You can use exactly same as with sftp; just write for example `cat << EOF | ssh machine_name`, write your commands and press ctrl+D (EOF)

Comment: Here's a *Useless Use of `cat`* Award for you. (`ssh < batch_file.sh` and `ssh <<EOF`)